# Do WEBSQL with HTML5 tables contain only two fields?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, html

I'm building a chrome extension, at some stage, I needed to create a table with 4 fields to store URLs. I took an example with only two fields first and implemented it, it worked well and I was able to add the values I wanted.

Now when I'm trying to add four values in the fields, only two of them are added as I want, the other two values aren't considered:

```
myDB.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO itemsTable (id,url,title,faviconURL) VALUES (1,"webPageURL","webPageTitle","favIconUrl")');
    });
// I'm putting temporary strings, I will get urls later
```

when I run this, only the id and the url values are added.

Comment: You'll have to edit the `CREATE TABLE itemsTable` query to create the additional columns before you can `INSERT INTO` them. Also, note that the WebSQL spec [has been discontinued](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/). You might try looking into [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB) instead ([support](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb)).

Comment: Okay, how can I do that ? is it important to switch to IndexedDB if I only need the database for this simple table ?